# C# Generics / General Types

Tags: c#, generics, types

```csharp
static Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> handlers;

public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

    AddHandler<One>((object rawOne) => { One one = (One)rawOne; Console.WriteLine(one.Data); });
    AddHandler<Two>((object rawTwo) => { Two two = (Two)rawTwo; Console.WriteLine(two.Data); });

    Handle(new One("Test"));
    Handle(new Two(123));
}

public static void AddHandler<T>(Action<object> handler)
{
    handlers[typeof(T)] = handler;
}

public static void Handle(object data)
{
    handlers[data.GetType()].Invoke(data);
}
```

For lack of a better way to word this: How would I go about making this in a way where I would not have to cast rawOne and rawTwo?

Basically, I want this:

```csharp
AddHandler<One>((object rawOne) => { One one = (One)rawOne; 
Console.WriteLine(one.Data); });
```

To look like this:

```csharp
AddHandler<One>((One one) => { Console.WriteLine(one.Data); };
```

But, I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Obviously I've got to modify the dictionary in some way, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static void AddHandler<T>(Action<T> handler)
{
    handlers[typeof(T)] = o => handler((T)o);
}
```

Furthermore, since the compiler can infer certain things about your types, you could say either this:

```
AddHandler((One one) => { Console.WriteLine(one.Data); };
```

... or this:

```
AddHandler<One>(one => { Console.WriteLine(one.Data); };
```

Comment: How would I add it to the handler dictionary then?

Comment: I apologize if I'm a little dense, but what would I change the definition of the dictionary to?

Comment: @user1438378 You wouldn't change it at all

Comment: If I leave it unchanged, I get an error notifying me that I 'cannot implicitly convert System.Action<T> to System.Action<object>'

Comment: @user1438378 Then you haven't made the changes described in this answer.

Comment: Heh, you're right. I typed it incorrectly. Thanks for the help, everything works now.